# Does fmt.Println have to be inside a function in Go?

Tags: go, syntax, grammar

Does `fmt.Println` need to always belong to a function?

Have used Python before and it allows it but on research, it seems that Java doesn't

```
fmt.Println("can I do it?")
```

Returns:

> syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go which explains in detail how to write Go code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be outside of a function, see this example:

```
var n, err = fmt.Println("I can do it")

func main() {
    fmt.Println("In main(),", n, err)
}
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f5jjSp9TEgX)):

```
I can do it
In main(), 12 <nil>
```

(The output values `12 <nil>` are the values returned by the first [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) call, the number of bytes it has written and the error it returned which is `nil` indicating no error.)

Also note that you don't even have to store the return values of `fmt.Prinln()`, you can use the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) like this:

```
var _, _ = fmt.Println("I can do it")
```

It cannot stand on its own at the top level "between" top-level declarations, but the above variable declaration (with blank identifier) pretty much achieves the same.

[Spec: Source file organization:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Source_file_organization)

> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use, followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types, variables, and constants.
>
> ```
> SourceFile       = PackageClause ";" { ImportDecl ";" } { TopLevelDecl ";" } .
> ```

Obviously a [package clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#PackageClause) or [import declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ImportDecl) can't contain an `fmt.Println()` call, and the [top level declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#TopLevelDecl):

> ```
> Declaration   = ConstDecl | TypeDecl | VarDecl .
> TopLevelDecl  = Declaration | FunctionDecl | MethodDecl .
> ```

A [constant declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations) cannot contain an `fmt.Println()` call, that's not a [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions). A [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) also cannot contain function calls.

A variable declaration can, as shown in the example at the top of the answer.

[Function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations) and [method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) could also call `fmt.Println()`, but you were asking specifically if `fmt.Println()` can be called outside of them.

So the only place it is allowed outside of functions that is allowed at the top level is in variable declarations.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

go always starts execution in the main function, so fmt.Println() need to be in the main function or a function that is called in main.

Comment: This is not true. [Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) precedes the `main()` function.

Comment: @icza yes, but he was asking about the python style of calling functions before htting the main function,